# Sum of Divisors of array elements

Tags: c

Today I was asked a C question in a company where i have to find the sum of all divisors of elements of an array individually except itself and store each sum in the same array.For example if array consists of  {10,4,6}.Then for 10,it should store 1+2+5=8 in place of 10,then for 4,1+2=3 and so on.I was given 4 variables only():- array[],i,temp,n(size).I could do it using two loops but it requires one variable.Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: You can use loops to process elemnts of an array, sure. But this reduces the question to find the dividers for one element. So 4 variables is three more than required. ;-) What have you tried so far? If it requires a variable use it. That's what variables are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you're given the array size as a **variable** `n`, feel free to use it as a loop counter:

```
while (n > 0) {
    --n;
    temp = 0; // the sum
    for (i = a[n] - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        if (a[n] % i == 0) {
            temp += i;
        }
    }
    a[n] = temp;
}
```